# Remix error message 'Unused function parameter' with fulfillRandomness using Chainlink VRF Smart Contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, chainlink

The issue is a repeated error message upon attempting to compile a verifiable random number smart contract in remix. This particular function (**line 48** in remix or **last line** of code below) yields the error message consistently across compiler versions (I checked the imported documents versions too), cross brave browser+firefox, and even after checking grammar. I do not understand what this error message is conveying (I am brand new to programming) and I cannot find another thread with this same issue. I suspect the function to be faulty in some sense of how it is either defined or interacting with the other imported documents (**VRFConsumerBase.sol**).

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBase.sol";

/**
 * Request testnet LINK and ETH here: https://faucets.chain.link/
 * Find information on LINK Token Contracts and get the latest ETH and LINK faucets here:
 * https://docs.chain.link/docs/link-token-contracts/
 */

contract RandomNumberConsumer is VRFConsumerBase {

    bytes32 public keyHash;
    uint256 public fee;
    uint256 public randomResult;

    /**
     * Constructor inherits VRFConsumerBase
     * 
     * Network: Rinkeby
     * Chainlink VRF Coordinator address: 0xb3dCcb4Cf7a26f6cf6B120Cf5A73875B7BBc655B
     * LINK token address:                0x01BE23585060835E02B77ef475b0Cc51aA1e0709
     * Key Hash: 0x2ed0feb3e7fd2022120aa84fab1945545a9f2ffc9076fd6156fa96eaff4c1311
     */

    constructor() VRFConsumerBase(
        0xb3dCcb4Cf7a26f6cf6B120Cf5A73875B7BBc655B, //VRF Coordinator
        0x01BE23585060835E02B77ef475b0Cc51aA1e0709) //Rinkeby LINK Token
    {
        keyHash = 0x2ed0feb3e7fd2022120aa84fab1945545a9f2ffc9076fd6156fa96eaff4c1311;
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; //0.1 LINK (varies by network)
    }

    /**
     * Requests fulfillRandomness
     */

    function getRandomNumber() public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        require(LINK.balanceOf(address(this)) >= fee, "Not enough LINK - fill contract with faucet");
        return requestRandomness(keyHash, fee);
    }

    /**
     * Callback function used by VRF Coordinator
     */

    function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomness) internal override {
        randomResult = randomness;
    }

}
```

This near identical code can be found at https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-a-random-number/ **(line 52)**.
Here is the error message below,

```
        from solidity:
Warning: Unused function parameter. Remove or comment out the variable name to silence this warning.
  --> docs.chain.link/samples/VRF/RandomNumberConsumer.sol:52:32: function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomness) internal override {
```

I am following the 'Getting A Random Number with Chainlink VRF' tutorial from Chainlink
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqZWariqh5s (timestamp @ 9:30) except I am testing on the Rinkeby network not Kovan. I also double checked with this tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_aXumgdpnPU (timestamp @ 12:00)
Neither tutorial encounters this specific error message and both are able to compile and deploy the smart contract successfully. I also receive the error message when I directly open and attempt to compile the smart contract from the Chainlink website without touching the code.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same error i fixed it by leaving the bytes32 parameter empty

your code
(bytes32 requestId , uint256 randomness)

instead use:
(bytes32, uint256 randomness)